# Why does ValidForm Builder not allow a field entry to begin with Pound-Sign?

Tags: validform

I have a [ValidForm Builder](http://validformbuilder.org) form. When I enter data into a field and the data starts with a pound-sign (`#`) the entry is rejected.

**Here's my code:**

```
  $objAddress->addField('customerAddressLine2', /*'Mailing Address',*/ VFORM_STRING,
    array(
      'required' => false,
      'maxLength' => VFB_MAXLENGTH_CUSTOMERS_CUSTOMERS_CUSTOMERADDRESSLINE1
    ),
    array(),
    array(
      //'fieldclass' => 'vf__multifielditemFloat',
      (($_POST['action'] == 'delete') ? 'fieldDisabled' : 'fieldEnabled') => (($_POST['action'] == 'delete') ? 'disabled' : 'enabled'),
       'default' => $default['customerAddressLine2']
    )
  );
```

**Here's the error:**

[image]

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [the Validator.php source](https://github.com/neverwoods/validformbuilder/blob/master/classes/ValidFormBuilder/Validator.php), `ValidForm::VF_STRING` fields don't allow `#`:

```
ValidForm::VFORM_STRING => '/^[-a-zàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýß€0-9%\s*.\'+\/",_!?:;()|& ]*$/i',
```

If you need to allow such a character, just create a custom field as described in [the (very minimal)](https://github.com/neverwoods/validformbuilder/blob/master/docs/documentation.md#custom-field-types) documentation.